Lockscreen ios widget expo react native
Anyone knows how can I create a widget displayed on lockscreen with my expo react native application ?
I have made some research and saw on internet it is possible to create it with swift UI and linking it with the app but I have been unable to find any code example or tutorial on how to do it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You will need expo config plugin that copies your widget Swift UI code when running expo prebuild. I believe this config plugin will resolve your roadblocks https://github.com/EvanBacon/expo-apple-targets
For creating lock screen ios widgets. Here's some tutorial references. https://www.createwithswift.com/creating-a-lock-screen-widget-with-swiftui/
Highly recommend you go through this arcticle. https://evanbacon.dev/blog/apple-home-screen-widgets
Hopefully it resolves your problem.
